# How To Setup A 301 redirect from an http to https in iis7

Tags: http, redirect, iis-7, https

I've read the FAQs and searched the help center. 
My URL is: https://www.loanfindersa.co.za

Hi Guys

I have recently discovered that the redirect setup for my site is a 302/307 one from http to https, which I know is not good for SEO as it should be a 301.And I see a lot of my back-links is going to the http one, obviously resulting in not passing the link juice to the https one, because of the temp redirect.

Can someone maybe just give me a how-to for setting up a 301 redirect through IIS7.

I did get this though:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/microsoft_asp_net/3939263.htm

Not sure if that is the way to go.

I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to go. Look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/05/23/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher.aspx